# Altering Nodecomment $links

Tags: 7

I am trying to alter the "reply" links added to Nodecomment comments when the nodes are listed beneath the topic. The problem I have is that I want users to be restricted to the inline submit form, but Nodecomment is adding links to the standalone reply page.

While trying to ovveride the links using hook_link_alter(), I ran into an issue with Nodecomment comments are treated much like regular comments in that hook_link_alter() doesn't seem to be run on them. Here is an example:

```
/**
* Alter module links. 
*
*/
function mymodule_link_alter(&$links, $node) {

    // This is an example of altering links that works as expected
    if (isset($links['comment_add']) && node_access('create', $node)) {
      $links['comment_reply'] = array(
        'title' => t('reply'),
        'title' => t('Link altered'),
        'href' => 'http://example.com',
      );
    }

    // This is an example of altering nodecomment links failing.
    // When rendering a list of topic replies, the comment_reply link
    // will not be altered.
    if (isset($links['comment_reply']) && node_access('create', $node)) {
      $links['comment_reply'] = array(
        'title' => t('reply'),
        'title' => t('Link altered'),
        'href' => 'http://example.com',
      );
    }
}
```

I am looking for solutions which can (ideally) be packaged in the site's custom module rather than theme.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation for [hook_link_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_link_alter/6) I find the following sentence.

> Perform alterations before links on a node or comment are rendered.

The hook implementation you are using is missing the last argument: the definition of the hook given by the documentation is `hook_link_alter(&$links, $node, $comment = NULL)`.

Looking at the code of [comment_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_render/6), which is the function that renders all the comments of a node, you can notice that `hook_link_alter()` is invoked right after the data is loaded from the database (and after `hook_link()`, of course).

```
if ($comment = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $comment->name = $comment->uid ? $comment->registered_name : $comment->name;
  $links = module_invoke_all('link', 'comment', $comment, 1);
  drupal_alter('link', $links, $node, $comment);

  $output .= theme('comment_view', $comment, $node, $links);
}
```

`hook_comment` is invoked from [theme_comment_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/theme_comment_view/6).

```
if ($visible) {
  $comment->comment = check_markup($comment->comment, $comment->format, FALSE);

  // Comment API hook
  comment_invoke_comment($comment, 'view');

  $output .= theme('comment', $comment, $node, $links);
}
else {
  $output .= theme('comment_folded', $comment);
}
```

`hook_comment()`, which is invoked with a call to `comment_invoke_comment()`, is not called for comments that are not visible.

The implementation of `hook_link_alter()` you created should at least check which comments it is altering, if it is supposed to alter only specific comments. At least, it should check the last parameter (`$comment`) is not `NULL`; if that happens, the hook is invoked to alter node links, which is not what you want as you need to alter comment links.

Answer (score 0):

If they are rendered like Drupal comments why don't you use [hook_comment()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_comment/6)?

Here's a kick-start:

```
function mymodule_comment(&$a1, $op) {
  if ($op === 'view') {
    // $a1 is the comment object
  }
}
```

Comment: That's gooding thinking! I'll try it on Monday.

Comment: good luck hope it works! :)